# VB.NET modify label in form1 from form2

Tags: vb.net, forms

I know there are a million topics about this, but every solution I found either does not do what I need (works only from Form1 to Form2) or is about C# instead of VB.NET

For simplicity let's say I have a Form1 with a label (LBLtest) and a button (BUTtest).
Then I have a Form2 with two buttons (BUToption1) and (BUToption2). If I click BUToption1 I want Form2 to hide and LBLtest to read "You've chosen option 1". If I click BUToption2 I want Form2 to hide and LBLtest to read "You've chosen option 2".

In Visual Studio 2012 I used to write in Form1:

```
Private Sub BUTtest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BUTtest.Click
Form2.show()
End Sub
```

And then in Form2:

```
Private Sub BUToption1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BUToption1.Click
Form1.LBLtest.text = "You've chosen option 1"
Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

And everything would work like in a dream.
Now in Visual Studio 2019 this does not work at all because it does not let me call anything from another form without declaring an object for the form itself.

Now I write in Form1:

```
Private Sub BUTtest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BUTtest.Click
Dim SecondForm as New Form2()
SecondForm.show()
End Sub
```

And in Form2 I don't have idea what I can write because if I use the same "Dim FirstForm as New Form1()" what the program will do is to create a new object Form1 that is not the one that is already open and I won't see any change in the open Form1.

(I also don't get why it used to be so easy in 2012 and it's such a pain now).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Note: It is important that Form2 hides instead of closing. In a different scenario there will be radiobuttons and other stuff and I want the selected options to be still there for modifications when the form shows again. If it is closed it would open from scratch.

Comment: You're mistaken that this doesn't work in VS 2019. I just tested it myself to confirm what I already knew, i.e. what you describe works exactly as you describe in VS 2019. If it doesn't for you in this specific application then it's because you have done something to prevent it.  Your code uses default instances and they will only work under certain circumstances, so you must have done something to create circumstances under which they won't work.  Your vague description of *"it does not let me"* doesn't help us determine what but, unless your VS installation is broken, it's something you did.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear but by "it does not let me" I mean that when I'm writting the code and type "Form2." the option for "show" or "showdialogue" does not even appear. If I write it manually it says (poor English translation coming) "The refference to a non-shared member requires an object refference". I have not changed any of the properties of Form2 and in previous VS editions I never had to do anything special to make these default instances work.

Comment: The only way I know to make that happen is to add a constructor with parameters. There may be other methods too but that's the only one I'm sure of. Default instances are syntactic sugar and still require the usual steps behind the scenes, which means that a constructor has to be invoked in order for a default instance to be created and that constructor must have no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going about this in completely the wrong way.  The proper way is for `Form1` to create a `Form2` instance, pass it any data it needs and then display it by calling `ShowDialog`.  When the user clicks a `Button` on `Form2`, it closes and the `ShowDialog` call returns.  `Form1` then uses the return value and/or appropriate property values from `Form2` as required.  If you need to show `Form2` again, you create a new instance and pass it any data it needs again.  You DO NOT need to hide `Form2` for it to maintain state.  You store the data that represents its state somewhere appropriate and then you use that data the next time you display it.

Here's an example.  I just created a project with two forms.  On `Form2`, I added two `Buttons` and a `ComboBox`.  Here is the code for `Form2`:

```
'The SelectedIndex of the ComboBox.
Public Property SelectedIndex As Integer

'The text for the Button that was clicked.
Public Property OptionText As String

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Select the same item that was selected last time.
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = SelectedIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Remember what item was selected.
    SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex

    'Indicate what Button was clicked.
    OptionText = "Option 1"

    'Close this instance permanently.
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Remember what item was selected.
    SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex

    'Indicate what Button was clicked.
    OptionText = "Option 2"

    'Close this instance permanently.
    Close()
End Sub
```

On `Form1` I added a `Button` and a `Label`.  Here is the code for `Form1`:

```
'The SelectedIndex of the ComboBox on Form2.
Private form2SelectedIndex As Integer = -1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create a new instance of Form2.
    Using dialogue As New Form2
        'Tell the dialogue what item to select.
        dialogue.SelectedIndex = form2SelectedIndex

        'Show the dialogue modally.
        dialogue.ShowDialog()

        'Remember what item was selected.
        form2SelectedIndex = dialogue.SelectedIndex

        'Display the text based on which Button was clicked.
        Label1.Text = dialogue.OptionText
    End Using
End Sub
```

If you create such a project and run it, you'll see that it works exactly as you expect.  The correct text is displayed in the `Label` on `Form1` every time you click a `Button` on `Form2` and the state of `Form2` - in this case, the selection in the `ComboBox` - is maintained regardless of how many times you open and close the dialogue.

Note that `Form2` has absolutely no knowledge of the existence of `Form1`, which is exactly how it should be.  You should avoid tight coupling like that if at all possible.  As it stands, you could use the same `Form2` class in a completely different scenario and it would still work, because it has no specific dependence on `Form1` or the controls it contains.  Any changes that need to be made to controls on either form are done only by that form.  Even on `Form2`, `Form1` simply provides the data via a property and it is up to `Form2` how to modify its own controls based on that data.

To show that VS 2019 supports default instances in exactly the same way as every version since 2005, you can change the code in `Form1` to look like this:

```
'The SelectedIndex of the ComboBox on Form2.
Private form2SelectedIndex As Integer = -1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Use the default instance of Form2.

    'Tell the dialogue what item to select.
    Form2.SelectedIndex = form2SelectedIndex

    'Show the dialogue modally.
    Form2.ShowDialog()

    'Remember what item was selected.
    form2SelectedIndex = Form2.SelectedIndex

    'Display the text based on which Button was clicked.
    Label1.Text = Form2.OptionText
End Sub
```

Run that and you'll find that, from the user's perspective, it works exactly the same way.  In actual fact, when you display a form by calling `ShowDialog`, closing it doesn't dispose it.  In the first scenario, the `Form2` instance is created with a `Using` statement, so it gets disposed at the `End Using` statement, which means a new instance must be created each time.  If you don't dispose it, you can actually display the same instance again.  That means that you can use the default instance and not have to remember the state because it's the same instance every time.  That means that you could simplify the code to this:

```
'The text for the Button that was clicked.
Public Property OptionText As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Indicate what Button was clicked.
    OptionText = "Option 1"

    'Close this instance permanently.
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Indicate what Button was clicked.
    OptionText = "Option 2"

    'Close this instance permanently.
    Close()
End Sub
```

and this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Use the default instance of Form2.

    'Show the dialogue modally.
    Form2.ShowDialog()

    'Display the text based on which Button was clicked.
    Label1.Text = Form2.OptionText
End Sub
```

and it would work as expected.  That said, default instances are something that most experienced developers avoid and recommend that others avoid too.  They exist for two primary reasons: to help beginners who don't understand how objects work and to help VB6 developers migrating who are used to forms working that way.  If you want to be a VB.NET developer, it's best to treat forms like any other objects, i.e. create and destroy instances as required.

Form more information on communicating between forms, you can read my three-part blog post [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html).  The first part is about default form instances.  It's worth a read but, as I said, I recommend against using them.  The second part is a hacky way to do things and the third part is the "proper" way to do things.

Comment: Excellent and detailed explanation. The default instance still does not work (it says "The refference to a non-shared member requires an object refference") but if it is a bad practices I will just ignore it as the method you propose works perfectly fine.